# In France: Replacing damaged ceiling light socket, how do I tell which is live screw in to attach live wire to?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I’ve taken the old one off and identified which is live wire but can’t see which wire fixing (small screw thru hole)is for live. It says 2A-250V beside one of them. Safe to assume that’s the live one?

Comment: We really need pics to be able to help you.

Comment: The best way is to test which screw connects with the centre post.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a 'bayonet' style socket with 2 pins, then it doesn't matter which one is live and which is neutral.
[image]
<sub>[Random Amazon Example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08FL9TKP7)</sub>

If you have a screw-in style socket with only one center pin, then that pin gets live and the outer ring gets neutral.
[image]
<sub>[Random Amazon Example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000HJ97AS)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

For a screw-in type light socket, use a meter (or verify by eye, depending on design) to figure out which contact goes to the center contact, that should be live, while the outer rim with screw threads should be neutral. That's a basic safety consideration.